# What's the origin of "wife-beater" when used as a sleeveless shirt and why is it not frowned upon?

Tags: word-choice, etymology, word-usage, american-english

I'm a native English speaker (from Ireland) and to this day I'd hesitate in saying "wife-beater" when referring to a sleeveless shirt. It seems to be much more common in the U.S.

Where did this term come from and why? [Another answer here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102333/alternative-definitions-of-wifebeater?noredirect=1&lq=1) gave conjecture that apparently it's from how people are dressed as they are arrested on the TV show "Cops" and/or men who commit domestic violence, but I find that really unconvincing to lead to such widespread usage while also not maintaining the negative connotation.

And how is it so commonly accepted without implying the more literal meaning? I just don't understand how it became natural usage and something people ultimately say without needing to clarify or lose a straight face.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59053/discussion-on-question-by-benny-lewis-whats-the-origin-of-wife-beater-when-us).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Three 1970s sources show that literal wife-beaters were already associated with wearing (just) undershirts by then.

[Wife Beating: The Silent Crisis](https://books.google.com/books?id=tewTAQAAMAAJ&q=%22wife%20beater%22%20undershirt&dq=%22wife%20beater%22%20undershirt&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDxteVtvTTAhVISCYKHaA4A0gQ6AEIKjAC) (1977) says:

> Conventional wisdom depicts the wife beater as a lower class, beer-drinking, undershirt-wearing, Stanley Kowalski brute

[New Woman](https://books.google.com/books?id=kqYbAQAAMAAJ&q=%22wife%20beater%22%20undershirt&dq=%22wife%20beater%22%20undershirt&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDxteVtvTTAhVISCYKHaA4A0gQ6AEILzAD) (1978) says:

> Conventional wisdom depicts the wife beater as a lower class, beer- drinking, undershirt-wearing brute

[Wife Beating Law and Society Confront the Castle Door](http://heinonline.org/HOL/Page?handle=hein.journals/gonlr15&div=14&g_sent=1&collection=journals) *Gonzaga Law Reviews* (1979) says:

> Contrary to what many believe, wife beating is not confined to the poor, "beer-drinking, undershirt-wearing . . . brute."

So this stereotype was already solidly in place by the 1970s, well before the TV show "Cops".

In the 21 August 1995 article [Fashion Ground Zero](https://books.google.com/books?id=5-QCAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA32&lpg=PA32&dq=%22stick%20thin%20blonde%20who%20cites%20archie%20bunker%22&source=bl&ots=eCRpdsTcC1&sig=3TTM8e1TnJ3kzSizzYmRWpa6WtY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwivne6nrvTTAhVEKiYKHc_dBoAQ6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q=%22stick%20thin%20blonde%20who%20cites%20archie%20bunker%22&f=false) in *New York Magazine*, Dany Levy describes checking out the fashion of kids at [Lollapolooza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Lollapalooza_lineups_by_year#1995), and begins with:

> Heidi, a stick-thin blonde who cites Archie Bunker as her biggest fashion influence, is wearing what she refers to as her "wife-beater tank," a  simple Hanes job dramatically splattered with mud ("$4.99 at Woolworth," she asserts, sticking out her boobs)

It seems to me in this early example that the author is a little uncomfortable with the term, but since this is a girl or woman saying this about her own shirt, and this was 1995, it didn't easily imply a literal meaning.

There was a 23 June 1998 article [Teen Slang for Undershirts ('Wife-beaters') Causes Stir](http://articles.sun-sentinel.com/1998-06-23/lifestyle/9806220147_1_wife-beaters-redneck-type-t-shirt) about the term in the Sun Sentinel. So it was frowned upon to some degree.

Comment: I think you're hinting at something important. A Streetcar Named Desire is the likely cultural touchstone that makes this correlation immediately understood by those in the 70s.

Answer (score -2):

As for the literal meaning issue, since you are describing a shirt there's neither explicit nor implicit reference to violence. If you were to pick up a stick and call it a wife-beater, there's implied violence. That's the difference.

Comment: This seems more fitting as a comment than an answer.

Comment: It answers "nd how is it so commonly accepted without implying the more literal meaning?"

Comment: That's just the nature of idioms -- once they acquire a common meaning, the literal meaning tends to be ignored.