# Is there a kind of heating system called "a beater"?

Tags: word-usage

I found the following phrase in a book.

"the monthly payment on their new furnace since ***the beater*** that came with their house died last month"

And now I'm wondering if there is any kind of heating system (or a part of a heating system) which is called "the beater."

Otherwise, is it just a typo? (maybe for "the heater?")

Comment: If it's a recent book, they may be extending [M-W's sense 3](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beater) from just cars to any old, barely-functional piece of equipment....

Comment: @Hellion's right. This use certainly gets extended. It's common for bikes (even in the UK where we don't really use it for cars) etc. On the other hand we can't out rule out OCR error without more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Beater* is slang deriving from *[beat-up](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/beat-up_1)*, referring to something worn-out, dilapidated, weathered, or otherwise *beaten up* from age and use. I like the [GNU CID definition](https://www.wordnik.com/words/beaten-up), which Wordnik gives as

> *adj.* worn by use into a deplorable condition.

The heater, in other words, was in such bad condition as to merit replacement, not repair or upgrade.

In my experience, *beater* usually refers to something mechanical: a vehicle, a tool, an appliance. By extension, however, since this is an informal term to begin with, it could be applied to most anything. Either a bent up egg beater or a tattered [sleeveless undershirt](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/392966) might be a *beater [of a] beater*.

> The police will tell you it’s not unusual for people to open their garage, find their expensive bike gone, and in its place find an old **beater bike** — the bike on which the thief arrived. —<sub><sup>Tony Brown, "[Lessons from scuttling a Minneapolis bike theft scheme[4](http://www.startribune.com/the-bike-guy-column-lessons-from-a-minneapolis-bike-theft-bust/479536823/)", *Minneapolis Star-Tribune*, April 12, 2018</sup></sub>
>
> [P]eople sometimes buy an old **beater truck**… Say hello to the concept of a **beater phone**.—<sub><sup>Catharine Hamm, "[The best ways to keep in touch with home while you're abroad](http://www.latimes.com/travel/la-tr-spot-20170903-story.html)", *The Los Angeles Times*, September 3, 2017</sup></sub>
>
> And it wasn't his fault UC didn't rate, in the eyes of the Atlantic Coast Conference, or that the Bearcats play in a charming old **beater of a stadium** we don't fill. —<sub><sup>Paul Daughtery, "[Butch Jones commitment to Cincy was pretense](https://www.usatoday.com/story/sports/ncaaf/2012/12/07/butch-jones-leaving-cincinnati-new-football-coach-tennessee/1754835/)", *USA Today* December 7, 2012</sup></sub>

Comment: Don't you think it would be weird to have a 'beater heater'?

Comment: @Mitch If I'm okay with a *beater beater*, I'm already operating from a pretty base base,wearing my dud duds in my flat flat with the crap crapper.

Comment: @choster _groan groan_