# What are multiword homonyms called?

Tags: phrases, rhymes, homonyms

For an example like “Francis Bacon” vs “France is Bacon”, what is this called, and how can I find more common examples of them?

It comes up a lot in speech recognition machine learning, or simply hearing someone say something totally different than what they really said.

“Fresh Prince” and “for Resh prints” could be another

Comment: Call them homonyms, too. Why not?

Comment: @JohnLawler homonyms have a different definition than what OP is asking for, so that's probably why they're looking for a more accurate word.

Comment: Related: [Equivalent of 'homonym' for terms and phrases](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48564/equivalent-of-homonym-for-terms-and-phrases). Wiktionary mentions '**oronym**'.

Comment: [What's the name for a play on words where two words together sound like a longer ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/386423/whats-the-name-for-a-play-on-words-where-two-words-together-sound-like-a-longer/386426#386426) is almost certainly a duplicate ('oronym' again). _"ice cream" vs. "I scream" /  "euthanasia" vs. "Youth in Asia" /  "depend" vs. "deep end"_ .... And [ Equivalent of homonym for terms and phrases]( Equivalent of homonym for terms and phrases) certainly is.

Comment: [What's the name for a play on words where two words together sound like a longer ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/386423/whats-the-name-for-a-play-on-words-where-two-words-together-sound-like-a-longer/386426#386426) is almost certainly a duplicate ('oronym' again). _"ice cream" vs. "I scream" /  "euthanasia" vs. "Youth in Asia" /  "depend" vs. "deep end"_ .... And [Equivalent of homonym for terms and phrases](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48564/equivalent-of-homonym-for-terms-and-phrases/48655#48655) certainly is.

Answer (score 1):

The only term for this mishearing of a phrase that I'm aware of is:

Mondegreen: a word or phrase that results from a mishearing especially of something recited or sung.

This term originates from (and mainly pertains to) the mishearing of song lyrics/poems. Though the meaning is expanded to any mishearing of a phrase that results in the listener perceiving an entirely new phrase with distinct meaning. Though it makes sense that the origin is from song since a lot of liberties are taken with pronunciation to fit a meter or rhyme scheme.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mondegreen

https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/mondegreen

Answer (score 0):

**Homophonic** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/homophonic)) (linguistics) Having the same sound; being homophones. Homophones can be letters, words or phrases (source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homophone#Same-sounding_phrases))

**Soramimi** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/soramimi)) A homophonic translation of a song lyric, typically humorous; a mondegreen.

**Mondegreen** had already been mentioned.